# Internet Explorer CSS for cell with div inside

Tags: html, css, border, cell, explorer

When I put a div inside a cell, the border of the cell is not properly shown in IExplorer: it is thinner for the cell that has a div inside.

Here's an example:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, td, th { border: 2px solid black; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><div style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:blue;">Peter</div></th>
    <th>Griffin</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lois</th>
    <th>Griffin</th>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried doing a "relative" positioning for the div and doing a "cellspacing=0" for the table and none of them work. The cell borders are properly shown in Chrome and Safari, but I don't know why IExplorer keeps doing making some of the borders around the filled cell thinner.

I've found a lot of closely related topics, but none covered this (or I didn't know how to apply it to this particular case). So I come to you in desperation.

Do you know any way to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm talking about IExplorer 11, I don't know what happens in earlier versions.

Comment: looks like it's because of `height:100%;`, not sure why but it's exactly the cause of the problem. although you can set `height:300px` or even higher, but `100%` causes the issue. Try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/a2T9x/

Comment: Wow! Don't really understand why (anyone?), but King King's solution fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!